# Test suite takes too long to finish with Jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

i have test suite that have 86 tests, in this test suite im testing a page in my vue app. and it takes an average of 500 secs to finish in my machine. it doesn't finish on my CI/CD setup.

now can someone point me to the right direction?

my code is optimized,
i am using only `shallowMount` and i am using `beforeEach` and `afterEach` for my test.

i also increased `maxWorkers` in my jest config and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who encounters this,
i was able to solve it by simply adding the below code in afterEach.

make sure to

- call `jest.restoreAllMocks();` if you used spy feature of jest.
- call `wrapper.destroy()` to destroy wrapper after each tests.
- call `mock.resetHistory()` if you are using axios mock

```
 afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    wrapper.destroy();
    mock.resetHistory();
 });
```